# kubernetes pdb ALLOWED DISRUPTIONS is 0

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to deploy a [PodDisruptionBudget](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/configure-pdb/) for my deployment, but when I deploy this example

```
apiVersion: policy/v1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  name: example-pdb
spec:
  minAvailable: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: example-deployment
```

with this deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: example-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: example-deployment-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: example-deployment-app
    spec:
        ...
```

I get the response

```
$ kubectl get pdb
NAME          MIN AVAILABLE   MAX UNAVAILABLE   ALLOWED DISRUPTIONS   AGE
example-pdb   1               N/A               0                     7s
```

What does it mean for "ALLOWED DISRUPTIONS" to be 0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned by [Specifying a PodDisruptionBudget](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/configure-pdb/#specifying-a-poddisruptionbudget):

> A `PodDisruptionBudget` has three fields:
>
> - A label selector `.spec.selector` to specify the set of pods to which it applies. This field is required.
> - `.spec.minAvailable` which is a description of the number of pods from that set that must still be available after the eviction, even in
>   the absence of the evicted pod. `minAvailable` can be either an
>   absolute number or a percentage.
> - `.spec.maxUnavailable` (available in Kubernetes 1.7 and higher) which is a description of the number of pods from that set that can be
>   unavailable after the eviction. It can be either an absolute number or
>   a percentage.

In your case the `.spec.minAvailable` is set to `1`, so `1` Pod must always be available, even during a disruption.

Now looking at your Deployment's `.spec.replicas` is set to `1` which in combination of `.spec.minAvailable: 1` means that there are no disruptions allowed for that config.

Take a look at the [official example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/configure-pdb/#check-the-status-of-the-pdb):

> Use `kubectl` to check that your PDB is created.
>
> Assuming you don't actually have pods matching `app: zookeeper` in
> your namespace, then you'll see something like this:
>
> ```
> kubectl get poddisruptionbudgets
> NAME     MIN AVAILABLE   MAX UNAVAILABLE   ALLOWED DISRUPTIONS   AGE
> zk-pdb   2               N/A               0                     7s
> ```
>
> If there are matching pods (say, 3), then you would see something like
> this:
>
> ```
> kubectl get poddisruptionbudgets
> NAME     MIN AVAILABLE   MAX UNAVAILABLE   ALLOWED DISRUPTIONS   AGE
> zk-pdb   2               N/A               1                     7s
> ```
>
> The non-zero value for `ALLOWED DISRUPTIONS` means that the disruption
> controller has seen the pods, counted the matching pods, and updated
> the status of the PDB.
>
> You can get more information about the status of a PDB with this
> command:
>
> ```
> kubectl get poddisruptionbudgets zk-pdb -o yaml
>
> apiVersion: policy/v1
> kind: PodDisruptionBudget
> metadata:
>   annotations:
> …
>   creationTimestamp: "2020-03-04T04:22:56Z"
>   generation: 1
>   name: zk-pdb
> …
> status:
>   currentHealthy: 3
>   desiredHealthy: 2
>   disruptionsAllowed: 1
>   expectedPods: 3
>   observedGeneration: 1
> ```

You can see that if the `.spec.minAvailable` is set to 2 and there are 3 running Pods than the `disruptionsAllowed` is actually `1`. You can check the same with your use case.

Comment: My case is similar to the question asked. Even I have replica set to 1 and in PDB minAvailable set to 1. It shows ```ALLOWED DISRUPTIONS``` as 0 but the problem is when I do
```kubectl drain node-1 --dry-run``` , the output still shows as pod evicted. Is it like dry run does not show errors ??

Answer (score 0):

No, with `--dry-run` you don't actually see what would happen.

Here's an example of a a drain with a pdb buget blocking the drain operation :

```
oc adm drain worker3 --ignore-daemonsets --delete-emptydir-data
node/worker3 already cordoned
...
evicting pod local-yvabro/evs-sysopstools-6b8845bfff-hg4hq
error when evicting pods/"evs-sysopstools-6b8845bfff-hg4hq" -n "local-yvabro" (will retry after 5s): Cannot evict pod as it would violate the pod's disruption budget.
evicting pod local-yvabro/evs-sysopstools-6b8845bfff-hg4hq
error when evicting pods/"evs-sysopstools-6b8845bfff-hg4hq" -n "local-yvabro" (will retry after 5s): Cannot evict pod as it would violate the pod's disruption budget.
evicting pod local-yvabro/evs-sysopstools-6b8845bfff-hg4hq
error when evicting pods/"evs-sysopstools-6b8845bfff-hg4hq" -n "local-yvabro" (will retry after 5s): Cannot evict pod as it would violate the pod's disruption budget.
```

Note : this goes on until it is successfully evicted or the drain timeout is reached (--timeout)

Actually PDB with 1 replica is not recommended, as it will prevent any drain operation.
Zero allowed disruption is not good...